# Porting Contacts

Tags: android, porting, samsung-touchwiz

I'm trying to port the Contacts APK from the galaxy S5 to the Galaxy S4.
I got a FC when I tried to launch the application. I would like to get some help fixing this issue.

```
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class <unknown>

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #71: Error inflating class <unknown>

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:627)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at com.android.dialer.dialpad.DialpadFragment.onCreateView(DialpadFragment.java:672)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1853)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5429)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    ... 12 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    ... 30 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/dialpad_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200e2

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3010)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getDrawable(XResources.java:797)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3624)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    ... 33 more

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:577)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:973)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3006)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3085):    ... 37 more

W/ActivityManager( 1126):   Force finishing activity com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity
```

Here is the zip containing the files from the app from apktool.
[SecContacts](https://mega.co.nz/#!zhxVjDiS!Xe1tAWdYBGHzNTdY7HLwKebfRNO1Q11agYLy0F5pvfE)

Comment: **1** - apktool exports the reverse engineered code in smali. **2** - you need another tool to convert that in java (baksmali, if I remember well). **3** - the source code so produced is practically unreadable.

Comment: Oh yes, I forget that that tool excisted.

Comment: I tried baksmali, but at the end it says that the folder doenst excist....

Comment: During the process, some extra folders are generated - if I remember well. so, you have to carefully select which should and which shouldn't belong to the project. Some manual fix is needed

Comment: I don't know what to do with baksmali, I used dex2java. I now have the classes and XML files but I still don't know where the problem is.

Comment: dex2java, right, not baksmali. I tried these stupid things a couple of years ago...

Comment: I am just you a couple of years ago ;p

Comment: So... try to forget nearly all about VB Net. concentrate on Android and Java